# Android painting app undo paths

Tags: java, android, path, paint

I am having some problems on a Painting app. I am extending the View class and overrating some of the main methods. Here are some:

variables:

```
private ArrayList<Path> aldrawPath;
private ArrayList<Paint> aldrawPaint;
```

-onDraw:

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    for(int i = 0; i < aldrawPath.size(); ++i ){
        canvas.drawPath(aldrawPath.get(i),aldrawPaint.get(i));
    }

}
```

-backup ( when the undo button is pressed )

```
   public void Backup(){
    drawRectangle();
    if ( aldrawPath.size()-1 > 0){
        aldrawPath.remove(aldrawPath.size()-1);
        aldrawPaint.remove(aldrawPaint.size()-1);
    }
    invalidate();
}
```

-drawRectangle

```
Draw a white rectangle where the user will paint 
drawCanvas.drawRect(left,top,right,bottom,myPaint);
```

-OnTouchEvent

```
1.Action down --> path.moveTo
2.Action move --> path.lineTo
3.Action up --> path.drawpath + path and paint added to their arrays + path.reset
```

-resize

```
*everything as a normal resize +
canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
```

**Problem:**

When i click the undo button, in theory the last draw path added is erased and it has to paint the paths.size()-1 on the canvas.

What it does: it just paints the white rectangle. Never the paths.

If you need more code or to ask anything feel free to do it.

Thanks in advance

**Solution:**

the problem was in the ontouchevent. Instead of using path.reset() you should use:
 path = new Path();

Comment: Have you checked (use logging) the size of the respective arrays in `onDraw()`? Also, I'm pretty sure you do *not* want to modify the path list in `OnDraw()`, because this is utterly inefficient. Also, try to use foreach loops, you are currently hollering for off-by-one errors.

Comment: hi! i've moved some code to the fuction backup in order to modify the path there ( i am going to edit my post now ). I've already Log the size of respective arrays in onDraw and seems to be correct ( each time i click the undo button it substracts 1 to the size....)

Comment: Let me guess: `path.reset()`<= You are not creating new paths in `ACTION_UP`, you just reset the existing path? Hence your path list contains a repetition of the same path with zero points (because you just reset the path). Please add your touch event handler code.

Comment: Wow ! that works, thank you very much, i am going to edit now the post to add the fixed code.

Comment: You should be able to give an answer to your own question. Please do this as it makes it possible to follow how the problem was solved.